# Post filter on subaggregation in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to run a post filter on the aggregated data, but it is not working as i expected. Can someone review my query and suggest if i am doing anything wrong here.

```
    "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : {
        "range" : {
          "versionDate" : {
            "from" : null,
            "to" : "2016-04-22T23:13:50.000Z",
            "include_lower" : false,
            "include_upper" : true
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "associations" : {
      "terms" : {
        "field" : "association.id",
        "size" : 0,
        "order" : {
          "_term" : "asc"
        }
      },
      "aggregations" : {
        "top" : {
          "top_hits" : {
            "from" : 0,
            "size" : 1,
            "_source" : {
              "includes" : [ ],
              "excludes" : [ ]
            },
            "sort" : [ {
              "versionDate" : {
                "order" : "desc"
              }
            } ]
          }
        },
        "disabledDate" : {
          "filter" : {
            "missing" : {
              "field" : "disabledDate"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

STEPS in the query:

1. Filter by indexDate less than or equal to a given date.
2. Aggregate based on formId. Forming buckets per formId.
3. Sort in descending order and return top hit result per bucket.
4. Run a subaggregation filter after the sort subaggregation and remove all the documents from buckets where disabled date is not null.(Which is not working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole purpose of [`post_filter`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-post-filter.html) is to run **after** aggregations have been computed. As such, `post_filter` has no effect whatsoever on aggregation results.

What you can do in your case is to apply a top-level [`filter` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html) so that documents with no `disabledDate` are not taken into account in aggregations, i.e. consider only documents **with** `disabledDate`.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "range": {
          "versionDate": {
            "from": null,
            "to": "2016-04-22T23:13:50.000Z",
            "include_lower": true,
            "include_upper": true
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "with_disabled": {
      "filter": {
        "exists": {
          "field": "disabledDate"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "form.id": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "form.id",
            "size": 0
          },
          "aggregations": {
            "top": {
              "top_hits": {
                "size": 1,
                "_source": {
                  "includes": [],
                  "excludes": []
                },
                "sort": [
                  {
                    "versionDate": {
                      "order": "desc"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The use case i have requires to consider documents with disabledDate!=null while computing aggregation. And once the aggregation is complete i want to filter all the documents with disabledDate!=null from all the buckets. So i was trying to perform a post filter after aggregation is complete to return documents with missing disabledDate which is disabled==null.

Comment: You cannot remove anything from the buckets **after** the aggregations have been computed. Using queries and filters you can only decide which set of documents will make it into the aggregation pipeline, but then you can't modify the buckets once aggregations have been computed.

Comment: Thanks for clearing the doubt. My use case is such that after i perform the tophit on the aggregation buckets if a bucket has a document with disabledDate!=null i dont want to return any result from that bucket.Consider V1 is disabled and is closest to the givenTime and it is returned as a tophit. If i perform a post filter nothing should be returned from that bucket. thats the requirement. But if i filter V1 document before aggregation then V2 may be returned which is next closest document to the givenTime from the same bucket. How do i achieve this? I got this working in SQL.

Comment: It may be a dumb question to ask but still, Can i add a subaggregation after the sort is done to filter only missing disabledDate? I tried but it seems to be not working. I have updated the question accordingly.